# Using cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY or color.rgb2gray for hog descriptor from skimage?

Tags: opencv, svm, normalization, feature-extraction, scikit-image

I want to train a SVM with hog features extracted by the
hog descriptor from skimage.
The images have 3 channels (RGB-images), which I want to transform to grayscale before extracting the hog features.
And here is the problem, when I use the following code from OpenCV

```
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

then I get features which are not normalized, that means the pixel values are still between 0 and 255.

When I use the code from Skimage

```
img_gray = color.rgb2gray(image)
```

then the values seems to be normalized, because the pixel values are approx. between 0 and 1.

I tried both versions for hog feature extraction and the results are similar but not the same and when I training SVMs then the results are also similar but not the same. When I train the SVM with the normalized images then the accuracy etc. is a little better, but not much.

When I look at the following link from skimage https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_hog.html then I assume that the images do not need to be normalized before using the HOG descriptor, since the astronaut image in this link is also not normalized.
Still, I find it confusing. 
Could you confirm or disagree with my assumption that it is better to use OpenCV's code than the code from skimage for transforming from rgb to gray?

The full code:

```
import cv2
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY
```

or

```
from skimage import color
img_gray = color.rgb2gray(image)
```

before

```
from skimage import feature
feat = feature.hog(img_gray, orientations=12, pixels_per_cell=(5,5), cells_per_block=(2,2), transform_sqrt=True, visualize=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Regarding grayscale input. If you use a grayscale image as input. The conversion to float or other-wise will not 
   have much effect. This is because if you peek into the implementation of skimage.
   You will notice that if the input is grayscale, it is converted to a float image internally.
   See [skimage hog implementation here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/d0c78d7809fd21116ac386f81ea964b8350b9813/skimage/feature/_hog.py#L179)

   ```
    if image.dtype.kind == 'u':
           # convert uint image to float
           # to avoid problems with subtracting unsigned numbers
           image = image.astype('float')
   ```
2. Regarding the normalization. The reason this is improving your hog output is because normalization
   acts like a histogram equalization. Effectively stretching or compressing the dynamic range, so that
   your image content is enhanced. This is the reason you are observing this behaviour. It is expected.

Comment: Only that I really understood it. Regarding point 2: Does this mean the block normalization and not the normalization of images before hog features are extracted? If this is the case, then it does no matter which of the above functions (OpenCV or skimage) I use for the conversion from rgb to grayscale?

Comment: Yes. That right. Block normalisation is doing this stretching at a local level. While normalisation does it on the whole image i.e global.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to normalize in range [ 0 1] but make sure the image has float data type.

```
img_gray_normalized = cv2.normalize(img_gray , None, alpha=0, beta=1, 
                                   norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
```

Comment: Just for confirmation, do you think that the grayscale image should be normalized before extracting the HOG features? Or is this not superfluous?

Comment: Normalizing from 0-255 to  0-1 won't have any effect on the result. However "block_norm" can reduce the effect of light variation.

Comment: ok, that explains why the pixel values of the HOG features are very similar for both methods. Then only the HOG features would have to be normalized before the SVM is trained with them.